# Get image as byte[] in android activity

Tags: android, image, arrays

How can i get the array of bytes from an image in a folder of my choice?

For example if i have an image in Camera folder how can i access it and retrieve it as an array of bytes?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this method work for you

```
public byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, buffer);
return buffer.toByteArray();
```

}

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer but this line     ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight());
returns null and i made sure bitmap isn't null. any sugestions?